# Error MSB4057 for msbuild targets with period in name

Tags: msbuild

I have a UI to call msbuild on a solution, and I want to be able to check some boxes in a UI to specify which projects to build in the solution.  I'm using msbuild like this:

```
msbuild mysolution.sln /t:"proj1" /t:"proj2"
```

Everything works fine as long as the projects are alphanumeric.  But when I get a project which has a period in the name:

```
msbuild mysolution.sln /t:"ABC.XYZ"
```

I get an error like this (skipping some irrelevant details with ...):

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
...

Project "C:\...\mysolution.sln" on node 1 (ABC.XYZ target(s))
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU"
C:\...\mysolution.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "ABC.XYZ" does not exist in the project. [c:\...\mysolution.sln]
```

Obviously in this example, project ABC.XYZ does exist in mysolution.sln.

Is this just a bug with no workaround?  Or is it expected behavior, and I need to mangle the name in some way for msbuild to understand what I'm sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in the msbuild source code within the method `static private string CleanseProjectName(string projectName)`:

[https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild -> ProjectInSolution.cs#L340](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/6851538897f5d7b08024a6d8435bc44be5869e53/src/Deprecated/Engine/Shared/ProjectInSolution.cs#L340)

We can see that it mangles the Target names, specifically, it replaces:

```
private static readonly char[] charsToCleanse = { '%', '$', '@', ';', '.', '(', ')', '\'' };
```

with:

```
private const char cleanCharacter = '_';
```

So a target name such as `ABC.XYZ` would need to be encoded as `ABC_XYZ`, otherwise it will not be found.

[2]: